# How is this integral equal to this natural logarithm?

Tags: integration, derivatives

I am trying to understand following problem:

$$\int {\sin x \over \cos x}dx = -\int {d \cos x \over \cos x} = - \ln \lvert \cos x\rvert + k $$

I don't really get the final step, are they equal because $ d \cos x = -\sin x$ and the double $-$ makes for a $+$? Resulting in the following:

$$\int \tan x = - \ln \lvert \cos x\rvert + k$$

I am not sure of this, because I don't know whether you can simply take the regular suffix of $dx$ and multiply it to the nominator. Or is the $d$ simply standing there because $\sin x$ was transformed into $-\cos x$?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: **HINT**: You are integrating $\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ with respect to $\cos(x)$ which is similar to integrating $\frac{1}{x}$ with respect to $x$

Comment: which is then in order $ln \lvert x \rvert +k$, right? I see that now, thanks. But how am I integrating ${1\over cosx} $ with respect to $cosx$?

Comment: it is with respect to $\cos(x)$ because you have $d\cos(x)$ in the integral. Imagine you set $y=\cos(x)$, then you would have $dy=d\cos(x)$ and your integral transforms to:$$-\int\frac{1}{y}dy$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoever wrote this didn't write out the full substitution $u=\cos x$.
Then differentiating both sides gives
$$du=-\sin x \,dx\\
-du=\sin x\, dx$$
and plugging into the original equation gives
$$\int \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\,dx=-\int\frac{1}{u}\, du=-\ln|u|+k=-\ln|\cos x|+k$$